# Настройка gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Развернул гитлаб примерно следующим образом:

```
user: gitlab
groups: sysadm, webdev
home: /srv/git/gitlab [gitlab/sysadm]
authorized_keys: /srv/git/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys
вебморда (основное приложение): /srv/http/hosts/domain.com/gitlab/ [gitlab/webdev]
server: thin [ugitlab/webdev]
shell: /srv/git/gitlab/shell
```

Морда и sidekiq работают нормально, но я ничего не могу сделать с репой. При попытке подключения по ssh мне предлагается ввести пароль от gitlab@host, хотя я создал отдельный ключ для своего логина, записал его через морду в гитлабе и убедился, что он попал в authorized_keys и что authorized_keys читается от пользователя gitlab, однако подключение все равно хочет, чтобы я ввел пароль от пользователя gitlab (http://pastebin.com/TmQDdxb0). Когда я добавил http remote (git remote add origin-http http://gitlab.domain.com/user/playground.git), у меня были запрошены логин-пароль, после чего мне было сообщено, что ремоута не существует (проект при этом вообще создан как public):

```
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'http://gitlab.domain.com/user/playground.git/' not found
```

wtf и что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как всегда это бывает, проблема оказалась в поставленных на папку разрешениях. SSH отказывался работать, пока к папке ключей имела доступ группа владельца, ответ нашелся в /var/log/auth.log. Первое время пробиться по SSH все равно не получалось, я на всякий случай принудительно сменил шелл юзеру gitlab на /bin/bash (по идее никакого другого и быть не могло), и внезапно все запустилось.
Параллельно с этим в первый раз не создался сам репозиторий, поэтому не работал http-доступ. При успешном создании репозиторий должен появиться в виде git-файла в %repos_path%/%username%/%reponame%.git (например, `/srv/gitlab/repositories/fike/playground.git`).